# How can I get the regex to work?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use a regex to find the parent node of the 16 digit number and return that whole section, but can't figure out how, so given:

```
<Details>
<CreditCard cardnum="1234567890123456" ccv="123" exp="0212" cardType="1" name="joe" />
</Details>
```

I want to return:

```
<CreditCard cardnum="1234567890123456" ccv="123" exp="0212" cardType="1" name="joe" />
```

I then am going to use parse the xml and get every attribute that is a number and remove it.

I tried `.*(\d{13,16}).*`, but this gets every character.

Once, I do:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml); // XDocument.Load(xmlFile).Root

IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = 
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length == 16)
                            .Count() == 1);
```

I can't figure out how to loop through each attribute in elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers, for example:

```
foreach(var x in elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers)
{
//If attribute is number, replace value with empty string
}
```

Note: I removed the int.TryParse for now.

I decided to do this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = 
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16)
                            .Count() == 1).Select(x=>x);


foreach(var x in elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers)
{
   foreach(var a in x.Attributes())
   {

   xml = xml.Replace(a.Value, new String('*',12));
   }
}
```

However, if I have a second element with an attribute of 16 digits, it only replaces part of the attributes value.

Comment: When it comes to RegEx I usually rely on prayer, cursing, and magic before they work properly.

Comment: Why not deserialize the XML? Or use LINQ to XML to pull back exactly the XML elements that you need?

Comment: if you don't want to deserialize you could also look at using XPath.

Comment: Note that the above xml can vary as far as the element, if all the xml I received named the element CreditCard, I would not use regex.

Comment: Can't use XPATH, LINQ to XML because the name of the element could vary.

Comment: Do the name of the attributes vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your XML can vary a great deal, I would do something like the following.

Assuming XML like:

```
<Details> 
<CreditCard cardnum="1234567890123456" 
            ccv="123" 
            exp="0212" 
            cardType="1" 
            name="joe" /> 
</Details>
```

Agnostic-ish code:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml); // XDocument.Load(xmlFile).Root
int ccNumber;

IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = 
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length == 16)
                            .Where(a => int.TryParse(a.Value, out ccNumber))
                            .FirstOrDefault() != null);

// Do not use ccNumber 
// Use elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers
```

This could be extended to include a number of attributes...

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers =
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length == 16)
                            .Where(a => int.TryParse(a.Value, out ccNumber))
                            .FirstOrDefault() != null
                           && d.Attributes().Count() == 5);
```

There are a multitude of possibilities that don't include using Regex nor hard coding XML element names.  I tend to use Regex as a last resort, especially if there is something better that can parse all the data for me.

**Update 1**

`elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers` are XML Elements that contain *1 or MORE* attributes that are 16 digits in length and are an integer.  That being the case, you can't tell so I would change it to..

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = 
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length == 16)
                            .Where(a => int.TryParse(a.Value, out ccNumber))
                            .Count() == 1);  
                            // Where only 1 attribute is 16 length and an int
```

Extending it again...

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> attributesWithPossibleCCNumbers =
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length == 16)
                            .Where(a => int.TryParse(a.Value, out ccNumber))
                            .Count() == 1)
               .Select(e => e.Attributes()
                             .Where(a => a.Value.Length == 16)
                             .Where(a => int.TryParse(a.Value, out ccNumber))
                             .First());
```

Comment: I like yours better than mine.  +1

Comment: Very nice: +1. Must look into XElement a bit more. Hadn't realised you could do this kind of thing so easily! ;-)

Comment: So far I get most of it, but I am a little confused between the first and second block.  After I find all the elements with 16 digit numbers, how can I loop through each attribute in each element.

Comment: Ok, I see the second one takes into account the number of attributes which I don't care about, but I am having trouble foreaching through the IEnumerable<XElement>.

Comment: Updated per your comment.  Returns a *list* of Attributes which might be a CCNumber.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Is there a way to return all attributes on the cc number element that are numeric?

Comment: The first block of code in Update 1 returns all the elements.  You can loop through those elements and call `.Attributes()`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote up another method to try out.  The regex now only verifies the attribute value and not the XML itself.  I have no idea what you're looking to return out from this method but this will at least get you started on not using Regex for XML.

```
[Test]
public void X()
{
    const string xml = "<Details><CreditCard cardnum=\"1234567890123456\" ccv=\"123\" exp=\"0212\" cardType=\"1\" name=\"joe\" /><donotfind>333</donotfind></Details>";

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    Console.WriteLine(doc.Name);;

    foreach(XmlNode x in doc.ChildNodes)
    {
        ExploreNode(x);
    }
}

void ExploreNode(XmlNode node)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);

    if (node.Attributes != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0} -> {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);

            if (attr.Value.Length == 16 && Regex.IsMatch(attr.Value, @"\d{16}"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tCredit Card # found!");
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        ExploreNode(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is nice, but as I said before, the xml string will vary meaning that the element and attributes will be called different names.

Comment: @Xaisoft: There's nothing in here that references element or attribute names.  Everything keys off the attribute value.

Comment: ah ha, I see, you are checking to for an attribute that has a value of 16, but you are partially using regex for that, any reason?

Comment: extraneous code.  first check was for length of 16 but then I realized that letters could slip in there without removing that code.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this out and let you know my results.  Thanks so far.

Comment: @Xaisoft: There's an answer by ErikPhilips that I think is better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:
    <[^>]+[0-9]{16}[^>]+>

Edit: This might be more efficient- <([^>0-9]+)([0-9]{16})([^>]+)>

Comment: Nice, This worked.  Now I just need to parse the attributes.  Would you mind explaining the regex.

Comment: Particuarly, the `^` and the `+` in the expression.

Comment: ^ is the negation, + indicates it was found more then once. These are basic concepts.  Why on earth are you reading files that has credit card information in plaintext?

Comment: [^>]+ means match anything except ">" for one or more times.
Square brackets around characters mean "match anyone of these characters". If you put a "^" in front of the characters it means "match anything except these characters".
+ means match what is in front of the + one or more times.
So together they mean match a string of characters which aren't ">". Following that, there should be 16 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regex to parse XML. It's not well suited to it.

How about using XmlDocument or XDocument instead?

Comment: I don't want to use Regex, but the XML can vary.  It might be called CreditCard in this case, but others may call it PaymentInfo, CCInfo, CCDetails, etc...

Comment: I was thinking I could use a combination. Get the number first and the child of that attribute and then use XDocument to parse the element